# Mixed C and C++ makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am trying to compile c and c++ file using Make.

I am not very familiar with make , and i have managed writing a simple make file below

```
all:
        g++ bits.c -o bits.out
        g++ bits1.cpp -o bits1.out

clean:
        rm bits.out
        rm bits1.out
```

g++ can compile 'c' file as well , so i have written g++ for all the files I am using here.

And I am trying to call one of the function in ".cpp" file from ".c" file .
And this giving me an error as "undefined reference to function"

To explain it , I have function by name "returnfun()" in "bits1.cpp" file , whose declaration is in "bits1.h" file and i have included "bits1.h" file in "bits.c" and calling the same function from bits.c , which is throwing me an error.

Is there are any other ways of writing makefile?

Comment: You can replace the first g++ by gcc. That not an issue with make files. You have to add the header files in your commands, too. You can leave out make all together and just compile your code on the command line directly. Once you figured them out, you can copy them to the make file.

Comment: `make` is a build tool, not a way of writing shell scripts that take exactly one parameter. Usually you declare *what* to build and the *dependencies*, i.e. `bits.out` would depend on `bits.c` and all would depend on `bits.out` and `bits1.out`. `make` will figure out the rest.

Comment: You are compiling with linking.  Use `-c` to compile objects, and then link them all together.  Or simply blob all source files together in one compiler invocation.

Comment: Not directly related, but try not to explicitly call the program you want, but instead use the variable dedicated to this usage, i.e. `$(CXX)` instead of `g++`. This will make things easier when it comes to portability. [See here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not in the `Makefile`. Your problem is with `c++` name mangling.

Try surrounding the function declaration with the following to prevent name mangling.

```
extern "C" {
    returnfun();
}
```

---

Your `Makefile` also has a problem, but it is a separate problem. The problem is that you are not providing all the source and object files necessary to run the program. The following is one possible way to fix it.

```
all:
        g++ bits.c  bits1.cpp -o bits
```

Comment: I don't believe it is a separate problem.  He will have undefined references if he uses functions from a header file that are never defined in the source that is linked.

Comment: @Aggieboy, It is related, but conceptually separate. Hopefully the OP will update his question with some sample source to make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks Merlin .It worked :) The problem was with Make file I was using as you said I was not providing everything it wanted

Comment: @pranathi, You are very welcome. Please mark this as the accepted answer if it resolved your question.